# jQuery selectmenu not working on iphone

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, iphone, jquery-ui-selectmenu

I've got a problem with jquery selectmenu function on my mobile. I wanna to make it work but I'm a little new to mobile type. I tried to search on google but no results.

After I select my menu item the menu disappears and nothing happens.. It just hides the menu again.

When I try to choose from selectmenu on my desktop site everything works well. But when I try it on my mobile site it doesn't work.. But when I tried to select on android device everything works.. I don't know if it's some kind of problem in iOS..

that's my site where I wanna to make it work: http://svatebniblog.cz/satebni-salony-dodavatele/

When I use it on my PC everything works fine, on android device also but when I try to use it on my iPhone on mobile site ( http://svatebniblog.cz/satebni-salony-dodavatele/?wptouch_preview_theme=enabled ) menu opens and when I want to select one of options it just hides.

I would appreciate any help. Thanks

That's my script for selectmenu:

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("#kraj").selectmenu({
        change: function( event, data ) {
            jQuery(".dodavatele div").css("display", "none");
            jQuery("." + data.item.value).css("display", "block");
            if(data.item.value == "all")
                jQuery(".dodavatele div").css("display", "block");
        }
    });
```